# How to access GetGlobalResourceObject()

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm new to c#. I have this class...

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;


public class clsErrorMessages
{
    string _sErrors;
    public clsErrorMessages(string sErrorTextFileName)
    {
        _sErrors = (String)GetGlobalResourceObject("resource","FriendlyErrors.txt");

    }
}
```

The compiler says `the name 'GetGlobalResourceObject' does not exist in the current context`

Do I need to include another `using`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [GetGlobalResourceObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.getglobalresourceobject.aspx) method is a static member of the [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) class. You need to qualify it as such:

```
_sErrors = (string) HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("resource",
    "FriendlyErrors.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks! This has got rid of the error. How come intellisense won't let me traverse the hierarchy like `System.Web.HttpContext` or similar?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by `traverse the hierarchy`?

Comment: I mean what is `HttpContext` a member of? Shouldn't everything be under `System`?

Comment: It's a member of the [System.Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.aspx) namespace.

Comment: I have something very similar but my method is static and it's giving an error, saying "An object reference is require for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HttpContext.get'... if i remove the static from my method, then it compiles... how do i get around this?